# DataGridView Validation

Tags: c#

For textboxes, I have a data validation method that's like this:

```
string allowedCharacterSet = "1234567890\b\n";

if (allowedCharacterSet.Contains(e.KeyChar.ToString()) == false)
{
        e.Handled = true;
}
```

The way it works is, if the user types a character that isn't in allowedCharacterSet, the character doesn't appear in the textbox, preventing them entering invalid data.

My question is: how do I apply this to a DataGridView? Let's say I have 3 cells - the first is a name, so I'd want alphabet only. The second is a quantity integer, so numeric only. The third is an email address, so I'd have numbers, letters, a period and the @ symbol in the allowedCharacterSet string. These things I can do quite easily, but as you can't attach KeyPress events to individual DataGridView cells, I'm not sure what to do.

Comment: You can use CellValueChanged, CellClick or CellEndEdit events. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview_events.aspx

Comment: Couple the above with a `Regex` to match you specifics...

Comment: @renamr CellEndEdit only triggers when the user leaves that cell, doesn't it? Do the others act similar?

Answer (score 0):

You must apply it in the DataGridView Cell validating event. Below is some example I did which is used to restrict the value to be in between 0-100 only. You can edit the validate.

```
// validation on dgvLotDetail's Yield Column (only numeric and between 0 to 100 allowed)
    private void dgvLotDetail_CellValidating(object sender, DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (dgvLotDetail.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[txtYield.Index].Value != null)
        {
            if (e.ColumnIndex == txtYield.Index)
            {
                int i;
                if ( !int.TryParse(Convert.ToString(e.FormattedValue), out i) ||
                    i < 0 ||
                    i > 100 )
                {
                    e.Cancel = true;
                    MessageBox.Show("Enter only integer between 0 and 100.");
                }
                else
                {
                }
            }
        }
    }
```